# Materialize css 'select' not working with django

Tags: python, css, django, materialize

I have this template that collects all names of authors from `author_info` model. These names are shown as a drop down list. When i pass the selected value to the view, it shows null. The template:

```
<select>
     <option value="" disabled selected>Choose author</option>
     {% for author in ainfo %}
          <option  value="{{author.name}}" name="author_name">{{author.name}}</option>
     {% endfor %}
</select>
```

The code snippet from views:

```
if request.method=="POST":

    author=request.POST.get('author_name')
```

Comment: i did initialise select as said in materialize css page

Answer (score 4):

It's null, because you haven't named your select input. When you're trying to get `author_name` from request, Django is looking for input named `author_name`. There is none in your case. Delete name attribute from options and add appropriate name attribute to select.

```
<select name="author">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose author</option>
    {% for author in ainfo %}
    <option  value="{{author.name}}">{{author.name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

and

```
author = request.POST.get('author')
```

Additionally, you could move input to `forms.py` and use it like any other form, validate selections etc.

```
class AuthorForm(forms.Form):

    author_choices = [
        (None, 'Choose author')
    ]

    authors = forms.ChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for author in YourAuthorModel.objects.all():
            author_choices.append((author.author_name, author.author_name))
        self.fields['authors'].widget.choices = author_choices
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initiate materialize select, to make selection possible:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
        var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
    });
</script>
```